# how to dismiss a UIAlertView once the data finishes loading from Twitter's API using SL Requests

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios6, ios7

I have two SL requests:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
#pragma alertView
    // load an alert to indicate that the app is loading from the internet
    loadingAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Updating" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];

#pragma activity indicator
    // create an activity indicator and dump it into the alert
    UIActivityIndicatorView *progress= [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(125, 50, 30, 30)];
    progress.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge;

    [loadingAlert addSubview:progress];
    [progress startAnimating];

    // display alert
    [loadingAlert show];

    // load the nib customized cell
    UINib* twitterCellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"TwitterViewCell" bundle:nil];

    if (twitterCellNib != nil) {
        [tweetTableView registerNib:twitterCellNib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"TwitterCell"];
    }
    // all tweeter operations need to go through this filter
    // create an account-store object
    ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc]init];

    if (accountStore != nil) {
        // create an account type
        ACAccountType *accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];

        if (accountType != nil) {

            // request access (on device pop-up) on sim. permanent
            [accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:nil completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {

                if (granted) {
                    // code that needs to exect if access is granted here

                    // get a list with all the accounts in the device/sim
                    NSArray *twitterAccount = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];

                    if (twitterAccount != nil) {

                        ACAccount *workingAccount = [twitterAccount objectAtIndex:0];

                        if (workingAccount != nil) {

                            // username of the account
                            NSString *userName = workingAccount.username;

                            // create SL request for user profile info ______________________________
                            NSMutableString* userProfileRequest = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?screen_name="];

                            [userProfileRequest appendString:userName];


                            // create an SL request for user information
                            SLRequest *requestUserInfo = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET URL:[NSURL URLWithString:userProfileRequest] parameters:nil];

                            if (requestUserInfo != nil) {

                                [requestUserInfo setAccount:workingAccount];

                                // perform request
                                [requestUserInfo performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
                                    // check response from the server
                                    NSInteger codeServer = [urlResponse statusCode];

                                    if (codeServer == 200) {
                                        // catch the user info from the api
                                        userProfileArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:nil];

                                        if (userProfileArray != nil) {

                                            [loadingAlert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:true];

                                        }

                                    }
                                }];
                            }

                            // create a string type url
                            NSString *userTimeString = @"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json";

                            // create SL request for time-line ____________________________
                            SLRequest *request = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET URL:[NSURL URLWithString:userTimeString] parameters:nil];

                            if (request != nil) {
                                // user needs to be logged in
                                [request setAccount:workingAccount];

                                // perform request
                                [request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {

                                    // check the response from the server
                                    NSInteger responseCode = [urlResponse statusCode];

                                    if (responseCode == 200) {

                                        // we are good to go
                                        // catch the feed
                                        twitterFeed = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:nil];

                                        if (twitterFeed != nil) {

                                            [tweetTableView reloadData];


                                        }
                                    }

                                    else {

                                        NSLog(@"Debugging Error: <the server response is not 200>");
                                    }
                                }];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {

                    // debugging: access granted error goes here
                    NSLog(@"User did not grant access");
                }

            }];
        }

    }

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


}
```

I'd like to know if there is a way to dismiss the `UIAlertView` after all the information is loaded unto my table. I looked inside the headers of the `Social Framework` but I can't seem to be able to find any method (something like: `SLRequestDidFinish` or `didCompleted`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*> I can't seem to be able to find any method (something like: SLRequestDidFinish or didCompleted).*

This is provided by a handler you pass into `performRequestWithHandler` function:

```
[requestUserInfo performRequestWithHandler:handler]
```

The handler is called when the request is done. Be aware that the handler is not guaranteed to be called on any particular thread.

You have two requests fired simultaneously. The order of calls to their handlers is not defined. This may or may not be a problem, you just need to be aware of that and make sure your logic is correct.

You call `dismissWithClickedButtonIndex` from one handler but not from the other which is actually called on data from feeds. Is that what you really wanted?

What **might be** a problem is that you call `dismissWithClickedButtonIndex` on an arbitrary thread. I suggest you call it on a main thread. UIKit methods are not thread safe (with a few exceptions) so any calls you make to update UI elements must always be done from the main queue. E.g.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{/*Update the UI*/});
```

Comment: thanks for your prompt answer. I tried adding the [loadingAlert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:true]; into the handler but the table still shows the data at least 3-5 seconds after the UIAlert was dismissed. So, in my case the handler is all the code that follows the comment "Check the response from the server". I think I'm missing something.

Comment: Where does your code spend time? Could it be that `[tweetTableView reloadData];` takes 3-5 seconds? Do you call `dismissWithClickedButtonIndex` and `reloadData` from the same handler (they are in different handlers in the code you showed)?

Comment: According to the code above, `reloadData` is called from `request`'s handler block, which is not executed on the main thread.  This is probably why the data is taking 5 seconds to show up.

Comment: Also even if you call `dismissWithClickedButtonIndex` and `reloadData` from the same handler you may not get the alert box dismissed after the table is refreshed because actual time of execution of these method may be reversed. `reloadData` is likely to dispatch asynchronous call on the main thread while `dismissWithClickedButtonIndex` may do the job synchronously (unless it adds animation). These are pure speculations on my side though. Just something for you to think about.

Comment: @dmitri, that did it. I'm still testing the app, but it seems like it works.